# How to set height of label which is inside of UITableViewcell?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

When I try to set height of label in cell which is set in Storyboard then it works, but when I try to set height of label which has it own .xib file then it's not working.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainArticleCell";

     MainArticleCell *cell = (MainArticleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell.mainArticleTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30); // NOT WORKING
...
```

I connect to label successfully because whn I try to add text it works.

```
cell.mainArticleTitleLabel.text = @"lorem ipsum text";
```

Where is the problem?

**UPDATE (improved explanation):**

When I check before setting height is like is set over IB and after seting in code is like I set but visualy in Simulator is same.

```
NSLog(@"%f", cell.mainArticleTitleLabel.frame.size.height);
cell.mainArticleTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 48);
NSLog(@"%f", cell.mainArticleTitleLabel.frame.size.height);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I even can change backogrund color (but seting height is not)

```
cell.mainArticleTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.mainArticleTitleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 48); // NOT WORKING
```

Comment: what you are doing in heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @rishi - - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
  return 166.0;
    
}

Comment: is this enough height to accommodate your label, you need to have this dynamically, which will fix the issue. You should calculate row height at your -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method, by calling -[NSString sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:]

Comment: @rishi - It's enough, because when I set in heightForRowAtIndexPath return 300, in simulator it shows white space under the label.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot do it in the

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

you have to to it in the heightForRowAtIndexPath

here is a code sample

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //in my case i get the text of the cell in an array
    NSString* theText =  [anArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //then calculate the texte size with standard text
    CGSize textSize = [theText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return textSize.height;
}
```

if using attributed text in iOS 6 use

```
CGRect rectSize = [theText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(labelWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:NULL];
```

and return

```
return rectSize.size.height;
```

I am using this in my code and it's working for dynamic cell height.

**EDIT**

I read the different commentaries. It seems my answer is useless as your problem is not in returning a value in heightForRowAtIndexPath as you are already doing it. Your problem is that it's working in storyboard and not in single xib. At that point I am of no help.

Answer (score 0):

After many and many triesI give up from that way and I try to add one more cell through TableView on storyboard and add custom class and it works.